# Wav converting with NAudio

Tags: c#, naudio, wave

I have a problem with converting the regular wav to a-law sound. I getting the bad quality when doing like that:

```
WaveStream stream = new WaveFileReader(in.wav);
var s = new RawSourceWaveStream(new WaveFormatConversionStream(new WaveFormat(8000, 16, 1), stream), new WaveFormat(8000, 16, 1));
var c = new WaveFormatConversionStream(WaveFormat.CreateALawFormat(8000, 1), s);
WaveFileWriter.CreateWaveFile(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\out.alaw", c);
```

---

Or rhe twise slowed sound:

```
WaveStream stream = new WaveFileReader(in.wav);
 var s = new RawSourceWaveStream(stream, new WaveFormat(8000, 16, 1));
 var c = new WaveFormatConversionStream(WaveFormat.CreateALawFormat(8000, 1), s);
WaveFileWriter.CreateWaveFile(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\out.alaw", c);
```

---

How convert the wav to a-law with good quality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the `RawSourceStream` in either example, and the second example will not work unless `in.wav` happens to have the right format.

Try this:

```
var stream = new WaveFileReader(in.wav);
var s = new WaveFormatConversionStream(new WaveFormat(8000, 16, 1), stream);
var c = new WaveFormatConversionStream(WaveFormat.CreateALawFormat(8000, 1), s);
WaveFileWriter.CreateWaveFile(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\out.alaw", c);
```